# Purple Screen After Reboot (Post installation)

Tags: boot, login, intel-graphics, integrated

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.03 on my PC. When I ran the installation, it worked well, initially. However, after I shut the computer off and turned it back on, I get the login screen, I typed my password and it hung on the purple screen. It is just a blank purple screen. I browsed the web and found that it could be the Nvidia driver causing this issue. For this reason, I removed my graphic card and ran off integrated intel graphics. Re-installed Ubuntu, and got the same issue in the same order.

Here are my specs-

- Asus M32 series
- Intel HD graphics 530
- Intel i5-6400

[Link from where I downloaded the ISO file](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

[I followed these instructions for installing](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview)

I used balena ether to burn the ISO file to a USB.

I also tried installing the 18.04.6 release but still no luck.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, would you be so kind to describe version of Ubuntu and name / type of your PC and GPU card?

Comment: It doesn't appear that the installation was successful. What version and flavor of Ubuntu are you trying to install?  Did you follow a guide or tutorial?  If so, link it here.  Also, did you verify the integrity of the downloaded ISO and does your installation media pass integrity checks? Please include more details and context so that we might understand the problem

Comment: The Ubuntu Version is 20.04.03. The computer is older. Its an Asus M32 Series. The CPU graphics are Intel HD Graphics 530 as it is an i5-6400.

Link for Download
https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Link for Instructions
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: I am not sure how to determine if the installation media or ISO passes integrity checks. I believe Balena Etcher (from Ubuntu instructions) verified the ISO integrity, but other than that I did no other checks.

Comment: Brief update as well. I tried 18.04.6 and the same thing happens.

Comment: Etcher will verify the flash integrity (between the ISO and the USB) but does not verify the integrity of the download.  Newer releases will run an integrity check when they are booted, but other methods include comparing the published checksums at cdimage.ubuntu.com with checksums run against the file using tools like `sha256sum` - You can also use the BitTorrent protocol to download Ubuntu in "alternative downloads" since BitTorrent automatically checks integrity.  Beyond this, are you trying to set up a dual boot config with another OS? Disabled secure boot and RAID?